# Searching for links HREF values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add a way for users to cycle through a gallery with arrows. I already have the script set up to use thumbnails with links to display larger images in a photo area.

The method I'm using to make the arrows work is to get the `src` of the current image, and search the thumbnail links for that `src`, and then find either the next or previous `src` based on which arrow was clicked (`.left` or `.right`).

Here's the issue: I don't know how to do this. I've got the script to find the current `src` when a user clicks on an arrow, but I can't figure out how to search the thumbnails for the same src or find the next or previous src.

http://jsfiddle.net/G5VAf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('img[src="'+current+'"]')` to get any images that have the same source. Presumably you want to use something like `$('#thumbnails img[src=...]')` or `$('img.thumb[src=...]')` to limit yourself to just the thumbnails.

Getting the next or previous image is a simple matter of using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Comment: Sweet, that's got me started. Thanks. As soon as I finish I'll accpe.t

Comment: Alright, script is done. Posted final script on JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/G5VAf/2/

Comment: @Rev, check my version of your script, you can remove significant part of your code, it is revision 5 on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

User `$(...).prev()` and `$(...).next()` in order to get next or previous image

```
$(this).prev('img')  // gives you previous img tag
$(this).next('img')  // gives you next one
```

Check your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5VAf/5/)

[$.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next)

[$.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev)

Comment: That's a start, but I still need to figure out which is previous and which is next in the thumbnails area, based on which thumb is selected.